# How much time does it take a human body to replace all of its atoms?

Tags: human-biology

Mikel Vsauce (Vsauce youtube channel) said in his video that it takes about 5 years for the body replace all of its atoms, while in asapscience youtube channel they are claiming that it takes 10 years. I am confused and I can't find anywhere the precise time it takes.

[Mikel's video (minute 1:14)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coGfGmOeLjE&index=37&list=UU6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Rm3-HA) 
[AsapScience video (minute 1:07)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Ni5HOdGtzM&list=UUC552Sd-3nyi_tk2BudLUzA)

Comment: It would have been nice if there were some references/studies for that claim. I'm not sure for example if DNA in neurones in CNS (i.e. brain) get replaced unless its through DNA repair mechanism but still, that claim should be viewed with some amount of scepticism until a study is put forward and the assumptions are clarified!

Comment: http://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-for-most-of-the-atoms-in-your-body-to-be-replaced-by-others

Comment: I also imagine atoms in the bone mineral that sets in the actual matrix doesn't change too often.

Comment: I expect this to have a mathematical model resembling a half life. Bone turnover is significant. Bone remodeling is part of the normal mechanism for responding to physical activity. Bone loss in space is also significant doe to this effect. http://cjasn.asnjournals.org/content/3/Supplement_3/S131.full

Comment: I don't think Iron would be totally replaced because we can't excrete it well. The iron in our red blood cells is very efficiently recycled by macrophages, and excess iron is stored in hepatocytes. If you really have too much iron it will accumulate as hemosiderin in hepatocytes, which is almost irreversible. The best way to treat iron overload is through regular blood draws, which is a non-natural way to remove iron, I don't know if men have a natural way to remove excess iron, so if the atoms can't leave, they can't be replaced.

Comment: Forever, since some atoms are not ever replaced: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/18427/155

Answer (score 2):

Not **all** the atoms in the human body are replaced.

Carbon atoms in tooth enamel are not replaced after the enamel is laid down during tooth development. This was demonstrated in the [2005 *Nature* article "Forensics: Age written in teeth by nuclear tests"](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v437/n7057/abs/437333a.html), where the researchers showed that the amount of carbon-14 in tooth enamel can be used to accurately determine date of birth.

Comment: Another good SO answer with more references and details of atomic replacement time for other tissue types is at [Are all the atoms in our bodies replaced on a regular basis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/18483)

Answer (score 1):

No. Some structures in the body are ever present from birth to death. The first things which come to mind are [nerves](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10416756), [the eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornea), the [auditory hairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_cell) in the ears and the list goes on.....

Comment: could you please reference this! I tend to agree with you but over time replacement at molecular level is not inconceivable for any structure in the human body hence it would be nice to get some solid references!

Comment: Sure but I have not ate today so I am hungry it will be a while

Comment: I don't know about this. While it's true that cells in many parts of our body don't divide and have to last our entire lives, the atoms in those cells might be turned over. While the same neuron may last for 80 years, it will have to make some repairs to the membranes, DNA, proteins, etc. Whether or not this happens quickly enough to get total replacement within a human lifetime I can't say.

Comment: @Bez i added references...if you would like citations that is possible too.

Comment: @user137 no it does not atoms are extremely tiny there are just too many of them.

Comment: Autophagy is the mechanism by which cells recycle their own molecules. I'm not aware of any molecule besides DNA which does not get turned over by autophagy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autophagy

Comment: @caseyr547 many thanks for the references and while I agree that structures such as neurones can not regenerate but they most certainly have turnover at cellular and molecular level such as ribosomes or mitochondria (mitophagy), which is what I think user137 was referring to (although this is not at atomic scale as such), which your references have not addressed but I'm no expert which is why I was looking for evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @Bez no its simple visible hair (the part that hits the drum) is virtually dead. the part that is alive does not regrow when damaged. dead things dont fix themselves. its there from birth to death.

Comment: there are also other atoms like mercury which in many do not leave the body once they have entered